# Creating a dataFrame inside a for loop R

Tags: r

I am very new to R and I am trying to create a dataframe inside a forloop.
When I print the data frame it seems that it only retains records from the most recent iterations. I believe that the values are overwritten with the new records every time the loop iterates. Is there a way to maintain the previous records and also update the dataframe with new records? Thanks

```
ttest.function  = function(x,cohort,sex,age){
    dataF=data.frame(Intensity=numeric(), Cohort=character(),Age=numeric(),sex=character(),Status=numeric(),stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

for(val in c(1:length(age))){
    string=strsplit(x[val],":")
    intensity=string[[1]][1]
    Presence=string[[1]][2]
    status=""
    new_age=age[val]
    new_cohort=cohort[val]
    new_sex=sex[val]
    if(Presence=="true"){
      Ismissing=0
    }
    else{
      Ismissing=1
    }
    dataF=(cbind(intensity,new_cohort,new_age,new_sex,status))
  }
   print(dataF)    
 }
```

Comment: `dataF=rbind(dataF,cbind(intensity,new_cohort,new_age,new_sex,status))`

Comment: also don't forget to `return(dataF)` at the end of the function